# VBA User defined Application.OnKey Shortcut using the Mac COMMAND ⌘ key

Tags: excel, vba, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to make a user-defined shortcut keys for Mac Excel in VBA, where I can use the COMMAND modifier key.

I can only find symbols for CTRL (^), ALT (%) and SHIFT (+), but not the command button. Here's a subroutine where I would like to replace the ^ symbol for something that implies use of the command button:

```
Sub createShortcuts()
Application.OnKey "+^{H}", "helpMenu"
Application.OnKey "+^{I}", "Encapsulate_IFERROR"
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot confirm because I have not Mac, but the asterisk (*) should do. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per FunThomas's link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey

**"There is no way to currently detect the Command key in recent versions of Office VBA. Microsoft is aware of this and is looking into it".**